# View Historical Attendance data for a day every 10 min

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table which contains Students Attendance, the schema is

```
StudentId   ClassId EventType   EventTime   
1           1       I           2018-10-31 07:00:00 AM
2           1       I           2018-10-31 07:02:00 AM
1           1       O           2018-10-31 07:31:00 AM
3           1       I           2018-10-31 07:45:00 AM
```

OutPut

```
ClassId     StudentCount    StartTime               EndTime
1           2               2018-10-31 07:00:00 AM  2018-10-31 07:10:00 AM
1           2               2018-10-31 07:10:01 AM  2018-10-31 07:20:00 AM
1           2               2018-10-31 07:20:01 AM  2018-10-31 07:30:00 AM
1           1               2018-10-31 07:30:01 AM  2018-10-31 07:40:00 AM
1           2               2018-10-31 07:40:01 AM  2018-10-31 07:50:00 AM
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for the "OutPut".

Comment: I need the count of students for every 10 minute for a given day, groupby Class, Starttime, Endtime

Comment: I found a way to group by data GROUP BY Class_ID_Location,  (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1990-01-01T00:00:00', Event_Time) / 10), but this results start and end time only when there is any entry in the attendance table for the given period, i want for every 10 min irrespective whether an entry exists in Attendance table, pleaselte me know if you still need more info

Comment: @Senthil_Arun, In your output I see count of 2 students from 7:10 to 7:20 when there is no event time for any students in your sample data, how did you generate the sample output for row 2?

Comment: The "Output" is the expected result, I dont know how to bring that.I can create a time dimension if needed

Comment: @Senthil_Arun . . . I suppose, for instance, that "I" and "O" have something to do with your counts.  That is only speculation, because your question doesn't explain what the logic is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the times.  One way uses a recursive CTE.  Then there are various ways to get the count.

```
with times as (
      select cast('2018-10-31 07:00:00' as datetime) dt
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 10, dt)
      from times
      where dateadd(minute, 10, dt) < '2018-10-31 08:00:00'
     )
select t.dt,
       (select sum(case when eventtype = 'I' then 1 else -1 end)
        from attendance a
        where a.EventTime <= t.dt
       ) as attendance
from times;
```